# jQuery get wrong data from input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, laravel

I tried to get value from input text with jQuery, but I only got the first value. Input text is looped.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="item-container-add">
    @foreach($cartCollection as $cart)
        @if($cart['name'] != 'asdfghjklkjgfds123890')
            <div class="row row-add mr-1">

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="id_delete" name="id_delete" id="id_delete" value="{{ $cart['id'] }}">
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-2 border-cart">
                    <button class="btn btn-del delete_button" name="delete_button" type="submit">Hapus<img class="icon-delete" src="./svg/delete.svg"></button>
                </div>

            </div>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
```

From those HTML, I've got 4 different IDs with their own delete button. When I try to click Delete, my jQuery function only get the first ID from those loop. It is supposed to get the ID where I click the button. Here's my jQuery function:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete_button', function(e) {
    var a = $("#id_delete").val();
    alert(a);
    $.ajax({
        /* some ajax function */    
    });
});
```

Image reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7cgf.jpg

Comment: ID must be unique per page, now you have same ID in your loop for each iteration. JS selectors will always take only first element with ID and never sees others

Comment: id should always be unique, do not repeat id.

Comment: `var a = $("#id_delete").val();` will always get only the first element that matches this. This is by design. What you want to do is use the jquery tools available to you to find the matching input on the button you click. `$(this).closest('.row').find('input.id_delete');` something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to remove the `id` attributes from the HTML elements you create in the loop. `id` values must be unique within the DOM. Use the common classes on the elements to select them instead.

The reason for your problem is because in the click event handler you're selecting the element by its `id`. As this is a duplicate, only the first element with that `id` is found, hence you only ever get the first value. To address this you can use the `this` keyword in the click event handler to refer to the element which raised the event. Then you can use DOM traversal methods, such as `closest()` and `find()`, to retrieve the value from the related field. Try this:

```html
<div class="item-container-add">
  @foreach($cartCollection as $cart)
    @if($cart['name'] != 'asdfghjklkjgfds123890')
      <div class="row row-add mr-1">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input type="text" class="id_delete" name="id_delete" value="{{ $cart['id'] }}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 border-cart">
          <button class="btn btn-del delete_button" name="delete_button" type="submit">Hapus<img class="icon-delete" src="./svg/delete.svg"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    @endif
  @endforeach
</div>
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.delete_button', function(e) {
  var a = $(this).closest('.row').find('.id_delete').val();
  console.log(a);
});
```

Comment: button does not have `val()`. Maybe `$(this).closest('.row').find('.id_delete').val()`?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, ID needs to be unique. You can refactor your code as below.

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete_button', function(e) {
  var val = $(this).val();
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log(val, id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete_button', function(e) {
  var a = $(this).closest('.row').find('input.id_delete').val();
  console.log(a);
});
```

That takes the button you clicked, `this`, and finds the nearest ancestor matching `.row`, looks through the descendants to find the matching input.